# How to revert to iOS 4.2 from iOS 4.3 beta?

Tags: iphone

Hello all
I just installed iOS 4.3 beta version available for developers on my iPhone4. Now I want to go back to version 4.2. But iTunes displays the version 4.3 installed. How can I do this?

Can somebody throw some light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you missed the **"Read Me Before Downloading"** section at the top of the 4.3 beta page:

> Devices updated to iOS 4.3 beta **can not be restored to earlier versions of iOS.** Devices will be able to upgrade to future beta releases and the final iOS 4.3 software.

According to Apple, anyway, no, you can't revert to 4.2.

Comment: Yes, these are meant to be deployed on development devices and you cannot rollback. Beta 2 is out since yesterday. Time to update to already lower the issues but you'll have to wait the final release to get a stable version if you installed it on a production device.

Answer (score 3):

Well technically if you have jailbroken before and saved your SHSH you can [downgrade your iphone](http://lifehacker.com/5572003/how-to-downgrade-your-iphone-3g%5bs%5d-from-ios-4-to-ios-313) (this should apply to all ios devices and exact steps may vary)